# Where clause that outputs the first of every month for the past year

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am pulling from a database and I am needing the first day of each month for the last year. This is for a report that will be run each month so I don't want to have to create an array and then have to update that array each month. So far I have it to where it outputs the first of this month:

```
SELECT
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.ARRAY,
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.S_DATE

FROM
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT

WHERE
(SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.S_DATE) = (trunc(sysdate) - (to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) -1 ))
```

where its output shows:

```
Array    S_DATE
1        5/1/2018
2        5/1/2018
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

Any guidance on how I could get this all the way back to 5/1/2017 with only outputting the first of the month, so I can keep my size down, would be greatly appreciated. By the way, I am working within TOAD.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to get specific dates from an existing table or whether you just want the first of the month for the last 12 months. If the latter there's no reason to query `SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT`. Do you need the `ARRAY` values from that table?

Answer (score 0):

I worked the question a different way. Here is the solution if anyone is ever needing help with this:

```
SELECT
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.ARRAY,
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.S_DATE


FROM
SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT

WHERE
to_char(SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.S_DATE,'DD') = 01
AND 
to_char(SCART.STA_FRAME_STAT.S_DATE,'YYYY') >= 2017
```

Comment: a sample output would really help us what you are up to

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using a recursive with clause. This will produce the first day of each month going back 12 months from the current month.

```
with dates(r) as
(select 0 r from dual
 union all
 select r+1 from dates
 where r < 12)

select r,
       trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1*r), 'MM') S_DATE
from dates
```

My Output is:

```
r   S_DATE
0   01-MAY-18
1   01-APR-18
2   01-MAR-18
3   01-FEB-18
4   01-JAN-18
5   01-DEC-17
6   01-NOV-17
7   01-OCT-17
8   01-SEP-17
9   01-AUG-17
10  01-JUL-17
11  01-JUN-17
12  01-MAY-17
```